# DragDealer slider javascript widget - which files to embed in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dragdealer-js

I want to use DragDealer slider library in my project. According to the developer, it's only 12KB, and indeed the dragdealer.min.js file is ~13KB.

However, in the [lib] folder there are other 5 files that seems to be needed as well (jasmine.js, jasmine-html.js, hasmine-jquery.js, jquery.simulate.js and jasmine.css). When I try to run the code with only the .JS plugin file, the slider doesn't work.

Can you please help me understand which files I need to embed in my project in order for it to work with the lowest file size as described by the developer.

quote: "The basic way to install Dragdealer is to include the minified script into your web page."

[The project page](http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/#demos)

[The GitHub repository](https://github.com/skidding/dragdealer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only to include `dragdealer.js` and `dragdealer.css`.

Yasmine and simulate are for unit testing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9za8m/